# How convert this C# function to F# function

Tags: c#, f#

I am passing some code from C # to F # and I come across the following extension method that adds some mongo settings.

```cs
public static class Container
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddServicesFromInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.Configure<MongoDBSettings>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(MongoDBSettings)));
            services.AddSingleton<IMongoDBSettings>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDBSettings>>().Value);
            return services;
        }
    }
```

I have the following transformation and everything is fine, the problem is in the lambda that goes inside the AddSingleton method.

```fs
module Extensions =    

    type IServiceCollection with
        member this.AddMongoDBConfiguration(configuration: IConfiguration) =
            this.Configure<MongoDBSettings>(configuration.GetSection("MongoDBSettings")) |> ignore
            this.AddSingleton<IMongoDBSettings>(fun sp -> sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDBSettings>>().Value) |> ignore
            this
```

This line return me the error:

**No overloads match for method 'AddSingleton'.**

**Known type of argument: (IServiceProvider -> MongoDBSettings)**

```fs
this.AddSingleton<IMongoDBSettings>(fun sp -> sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDBSettings>>().Value) |> ignore
```

What is the correct way to convert that lambda function to F#?

Thanks for reading, I'm new to F#

Comment: The type of `sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDBSettings>>().Value` is probably `MongoDBSettings`, not `IMongoDBSettings`, right? F# does not have automatic type coercion, you have to cast it manually: `...Value :> IMongoDBSettings`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this way:

```
module Extensions =    

    type IServiceCollection with
        member this.AddMongoDBConfiguration(configuration: IConfiguration) =
            this.Configure<MongoDBSettings>(configuration.GetSection("MongoDBSettings")) |> ignore
            this.AddSingleton<IMongoDBSettings>(Func<_,_>(fun (sp: IServiceProvider) -> 
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDBSettings>>().Value :> IMongoDBSettings)) |> ignore
            this
```

So you need to convert F# function to `System.Func` (you also need to `open System` namespace by the way), annotate the type of parameter (`sp: IServiceProvider`) and up-cast result to interface `IMongoDBSettings` by using `:>` operator, since F# does not implicitly do such conversions.